# Only allow image on ajax upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am working on a project where user have to upload an image before submitting a form. Currently my code is working but it is selecting any format size which is not required in my project so my goal is to restrict the user to select only the image file format which is define such as jpg, jpeg and png from  I want user to only select the jpg, png and jpeg file.

Here is my working code:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#multi-cropper', function(e){
$('#cropModal').modal('hide');
e.preventDefault();

 $('#loadingBarModal').modal({
  backdrop: 'static',
  keyboard: false
});

$.ajax({

    xhr: function() {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                percentComplete = percentComplete*100;
                $('.myprogress-bar').css('width', 
                Math.ceil(percentComplete)+'%');
                $('.myprogress-bar').html(Math.ceil(percentComplete)+'%');
            }
       }, false);

       xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
           if (evt.lengthComputable) {
               var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
               percentComplete = percentComplete*100;

               $('.myprogress-bar').css('width', 
            Math.ceil(percentComplete)+'%');
                $('.myprogress-bar').html(Math.ceil(percentComplete)+'%');
           }
       }, false);

       return xhr;
    },

      url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>/user/crop_image',
      data: new FormData(this),
      contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType:"json",

    success: function(data){
        $('#loadingBarModal').modal('hide');
         $('.myprogress-bar').css('width', '0%');



                    if(data.status == 1){
            $('.preview-image-'+action_image_id).attr('src', '<?php echo 
           base_url(); ?>uploads/'+data.base_name);
            $('.prev'+action_image_id).show();
            $('.preview-image-
           '+action_image_id).addClass('preview_this_image');
            $('#image-src-'+action_image_id).val(data.base_name);
            action_image_id = 0;
            //$('#delete_this'+action_image_id).show();
        }

        $.unblockUI();
        reload_div();
          }
        });
       });



function reload_div(){


    $.post('<?php echo base_url(); ?>user/get_modal', {}, function(data){
        $('.temprary-data').html(data);
    });
}
reload_div();
```

Comment: Check this [class](https://github.com/shubhamoy/photolia/blob/master/includes/Pics.php) I wrote for a hobby project which handles the MIME Type Checking. Try to implement it as per your need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Than you can check type of image before upload**

```
var ext = $('[name="image_url"]').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
                                    if($.inArray(ext, ['gif','png','jpg','jpeg']) == -1) {
                                        alert('invalid extension!');
                                        blah = 1;
                                        return false;
                                    } else {
                                        valid_frm = 1;
                                    }
```

Comment: Its not working.

Comment: This only checks the file extension. It's possible the file could be malicious, and just saved with a `jpg` extension. It's far better to check the MIME type.

Comment: On my code If I select image its shows first on modal and if I don't select image so its shows image alt text. Also modal shows upload button. Can it be possible to hide the button when its shows alt text

Comment: I use image code this: <img class="img-responsive my-crop-image-div" id="image" src="" width="100%" style="width:100%;" alt="Only supported formats are jpeg and png">